# i cant open tor. im from argentina and this is the error

Tags: configuration, connection

```
2/14/19, 22:05:08.706 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 22:05:08.706 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 22:05:08.706 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 22:05:08.707 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 22:05:08.707 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 22:05:08.707 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/14/19, 22:05:10.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/14/19, 22:05:11.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
2/14/19, 22:05:11.360 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
2/14/19, 22:05:11.671 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
2/14/19, 22:05:15.600 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 5 hours, 5 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
2/14/19, 22:05:15.601 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Clock skew -18359 in NETINFO cell from OR; CLOCK_SKEW; count 2; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443) 
2/14/19, 22:05:15.657 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 22:05:15.658 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Answer (score 1):

the messages are there for a reason... please read it and act accordingly:

> Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 5 hours, 5 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings.

it seems that your clock is out of sync... please try to connect again (to rule out if it was a server issue), if you get the same error message again set the correct time on your machine. - IIRC your hardware clock should be in UTC!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ntp installed and set up correctly

Other, you may need a bridge if your network is censored or blocks Tor